# Adding two rooms in a basement

Tags: basement, ceiling

The ceiling height in the basement is 78" (under the 7' requirement for bedrooms).  I asked an inspector if it would be OK to add two rooms with closets and call them storage rooms when listing the house.  The inspector said that would be fine.  I had the rooms framed in with closets and electrical.  The inspector came to look and is now telling me they are intended to be bedrooms and won't sign off.  Does it matter what they look like as long as the house is not listed with bedrooms in the basement?

Comment: That will depend entirely on your location, jurisdiction & building regs you are subject to.

Comment: AIUI, if you don't meet code, you'd have to apply for a variance. Your inspector is the one who determines if you meet code. I'd venture to say that if you installed built-in shelving along all the walls, you'd have a much better chance of getting it approved, but still, that's up to your inspector. It sounds like you want to make bedrooms, but don't want to meet code. Code generally also calls for an emergency exit directly from each bedroom, so maybe you can point out that you don't have those, therefore it's _not_ a bedroom...

Comment: Is your basement a walk-out, does it have a door, does it have a fire window?

Comment: "*I had the rooms framed in with closets*" Remove the closets, they make the rooms bedrooms. Put up some storage shelves for the inspection.

Comment: @AlaskaMan - there is something wrong here.   Nothing makes a room a bedroom if it doesn't meet other guidelines.    Either we are missing info or they have an inspector who is either an idiot or way overstepping his bounds.

Comment: No matter what is or is not in the room, it is not a bedroom until used as a bedroom. *However*, the AHJ thinks he **knows** that the intent is to use them as bedrooms... so you need to deal with him. Ask him what it will take for him to sign off on the construction of these "bonus rooms".

Answer (score 1):

I was taught that: “If it looks like a hot dog stand, works like a hot dog stand, then it’s a hot dog stand.”

Working hard to trick people into thinking they’re getting 2 free bedrooms in the basement, is not commendable. You know they are not bedrooms, do you think it’s right to have family and friends sleeping in an unsafe room?

You are no better than one of those phone scammers.

Btw, the Code says the required ceiling height of “habitable rooms”is 7’, except in a basement, where it’s 80”. (See ICC R305.1) If the rooms are going to be bedrooms, then they need egress windows and smoke detectors. (Closets do not define what a bedroom is...)

Also, the floor area of each shall be a minimum of 70 square feet with the smallest dimension to be at least 7’ in any direction. (See ICC R304.3)